# Is it possible to match more than one regular expression with a single <ProxyMatch> rule?

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.2, mod-proxy, regex

I have a production, testing, and development server for a site that I maintain. All three servers are running Apache 2.2.16 on Debian 6 GNU/Linux. I have set up a new version of our company site on the testing server, and my team determined it to be stable enough to move to production. However, I want to make this transition as seamless as possible. I would like to be able to forward requests at production server so they are handled by the testing server. This way, I can test out this new implementation without making any complex configuration changes on the production server.

Ideally, I can use Apache's `mod_proxy` module to set up a reverse proxy so that I can serve pages directly from the testing server to production clients. I read the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html, which was very helpful to me. I enabled `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`, then I set the following rules on my development server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    # ... other <VirtualHost>-specific settings ...

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://test.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://test.example.com

    # ... various <Directory> directives ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This worked very well. When I accessed the development server, the site served all pages directly from the testing server, and it appeared as if these responses came directly from the server I had connected to. Moreover, these requests were rather snappy, and I was able to make both GET and POST requests as if I was talking directly to the testing server.

Unfortunately, this does not fit all of my needs. Since the testing server only runs Apache with a new version of the site, I cannot host webmail or userdirs from the testing server. These requests must be handled by the production server.

I want my production server to be able to use the reverse proxy for all pages *except* `/webmail` and the user directories (any directory starting with a tilde). In theory this is possible with `<ProxyMatch>` directive. However, I do not have sufficient regex-fu to do this. Is there a single rule capable of excluding both of these types of requests from being sent to the proxy server?

**Bonus points:** I am looking for a good introductory guide to PCRE's, so that I can write my own rules. Does anyone have a recommendation for a regex newbie?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one regular expression in the directive - but you can have a regular expression which implements complex logic:

```
/http:\/\/test.example.com\/\/(?!webmail)/
```

I'd recommend the O'Reilly book [Mastering regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570) but its not an introductory text.

There's lots of online material to get you started. There's a [basic tutorial here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). But I'd suggest getting a good book on the topic too (but I can't recommend on from personal experience).